# kubectl not working from other host, but works fine from localhost

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

**What happened**:

I'm testing kubernetes 1.9.0 to upgrade production cluster and I cannot access it with kubectl from other host.

I'm getting following error:

`pods is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list pods in the namespace \"default\"`

I tried with admin user and with other user created before with read only role.

**What you expected to happen**:

Works fine on kubernetes 1.5

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible)**:

I installed kubernetes 1.9.0 with kubeadm.

I can access to local cluster from master with following command:
kubectl --kubeconfig kubeconfig get pods

with server: https://127.0.0.1:6443

I added a rule on haproxy to redirect that port to another, but I do some tests:

- Old environment have a proxy configured to all requests asking for https://example.org/api/k8s will be redirect to k8s api endpoint.
- I configured this new environment with same configuration but not working. (Error: pods is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list pods in the namespace \"default\" )
- I configured this new enviroment with a new DNS name and proxying on tcp mode linking port 443 to 6443, but not working. (Error: pods is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list pods in the namespace \"default\" )

kubeconfig file set server field as: https://k8s.example.org

**Anything else we need to know?**:

kubeconfig file (kubeconfig for admin user is similar):

`
api

```
Version: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ***
    server: https://127.0.0.1:6443
    #server: https://k.example.org
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    namespace: default
    user: read_only
  name: read_only-context
current-context: read_only-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: read_only
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    client-certificate: /etc/kubernetes/users/read_only/read_only.crt
    client-key: /etc/kubernetes/users/read_only/read_only.key
    user
```

name: read_only
`

**Environment**:

- Kubernetes version (use `kubectl version`): 1.9.0
- Cloud provider or hardware configuration: bare metal (in fact a VM on AWS)
- OS (e.g. from /etc/os-release): Centos 7
- Kernel (e.g. `uname -a`): 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64
- Install tools: kubeadm
- Others:

Comment: RBAC is a sharp edged sword; you may enjoy [turning on RBAC audit logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/) to see what is currently happening, and you may similarly enjoy [audit2rbac](https://github.com/liggitt/audit2rbac#readme) to formalize the policies based on the actual interactions